# Recognize International Phone Numbers with Azure Recognized Named Entities

Tags: .net, azure, azure-cognitive-services

I am using the Azure `TextAnalyticsClient` to recognize entities but in the document I am passing through has phone numbers which are formatted differently.

For example, 07890123456 would be recognized as a phone number but formatted like this; +44 7890 123456 are not recognized as entities at all.

Is there any way I can get it recognizing different formats of phone numbers regardless of the country etc

Code Example:

```
var response = _textAnalyticsClient.RecognizeEntities(batch);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Text Analytics service's entity recognition capabilities may not recognize phone numbers in all possible formats, especially international phone numbers.

One possible solution to improve the recognition of phone numbers in different formats, including international numbers, by preprocessing your text data to a standard format.

Below is sample preprocessing step which removes the space in between the phone number.

```cs
string document = "07890123456 would be recognized as a phone number but formatted like this; +44 7890 123456 are not recognized as entities at all";
document = Regex.Replace(document, @"\+\d{2}\s\d{4}\s\d{6}", match => match.Value.Replace(" ", ""));
```

With above change, I was able to get the phone number recognized.

**Output:**
[image]
With this you can configure the preprocessing step according to your requirement.

Comment: Awesome, I will try that and see how I get on. Thank you!

Comment: I will when I have had chance to test it, thank you